# Image Not Resizing Properly in Minimized Firefox Window

Tags: css, image, firefox, resize

I am working on a site. The problem page in question is here:

http://bit.ly/I4YR2T

Currently I have the images in a table. I am also using Shadowbox for these images.

When I minimize the browser window in Chrome and Safari, the images scale down nicely.

However, the images are not scaling down nicely when I minimize the window in Firefox.

This page has the most images and is the most troubling, though I notice that the site as a whole does not scale down as nicely in Firefox as it does in Chrome & Safari. I have not yet checked IE.

I know this must be due to some shoddy CSS on my part.

Can anyone guide me on how to resolve this problem?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

see [this answer](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923710/why-do-firefox-and-opera-ignore-max-width-inside-of-display-table-cell&ei=wkCBT6XzAeSUiAed4M2nBA&usg=AFQjCNHHC_gyN1mRmjKDeT2Cozx1surFGw&sig2=IZhsueSQhNNzC-AZ7nhMHA) "Max-width does not apply to inline elements so you will get inconsistent behaviour cross browser...you may achieve it if you set div img { display:block } and then align the img... tags with floats instead of standard inline." That probably means getting rid of your table or setting the table cells to display as block.

Comment: Thank you! So this is a test page (http://bit.ly/HrMqiT) I've made in which the images are no longer in a table; they are just floated. However, when I mimimize the window again in any browser the images spill out over the container. Do you have any guidance on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The images you've got on that page are in a fixed width container. The images will only re-size if the container they are in is of a fluid width and this is not standard for a sldier. This slider will do it for you though, I've used it before and it works well - http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've figured out a workaround, but Blueberry looks very promising for future work.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem with Firefox. I got it to work in Chrome but Firefox wouldn’t display the code. So here is what I did:

```css
/* begin HeaderObject */
.banner-img {
  display: block; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  max-width: 99%;
  left: 50%; 
}
/* end HeaderObject */
```

I changed the `max-width` to 99% and it displayed correctly and resized correctly. The header object was placed inside the header on the CSS, so by chance I tested to see if I could get it to work with a smaller width, as it was “nested” inside the header. Then I added the `left: 50%;` code because I wanted my image to display centered. Working great now.