# Max-width in the table

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html-table, css

I have a problem with display of img in the table:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <div>    
        <img src="https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo4w.png"/>
        <img src="http://pictar.ru/data/media/24/nature__463_.jpg"/>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

with css:

```
div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border:2px solid red;
}
div img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SerCe/TAE3w/3/). 
In Chrome both images scaling proportionally to div-wrapper, but in Firefox and IE9 images do not scale.

How can I get Chrome behaviour everywhere?

**ANSWER:**  The only solution is to use javascript. My cross-browser solution is: http://jsfiddle.net/TAE3w/21/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to set the width to 100% also.

```
div img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/TAE3w/9/

The most consistent effect on all three browsers would be:

```
div img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/TAE3w/15/

See related questions:

- [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a div container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/image-auto-resize-to-fit-div-container)
- [How do I fit an image (img) inside a div and keep the aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394309/how-do-i-fit-an-image-img-inside-a-div-and-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

Comment: But in this case Google image scaling wider than it actually is

Comment: It is interesting, but my issue is to make the behavior of all three browsers in the same way as the first example in chrome, my problem particularly described [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923710/why-do-firefox-and-opera-ignore-max-width-inside-of-display-table-cell), but solutions do not works for me

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox max-width doesn't work if specified as percentage but works if given an exact value.
Use javascript to set maxWidth to image width.
No wrapper is needed.

```
<img onload="this.style.maxWidth=(this.getAttribute('width')?this.getAttribute('width'):this.naturalWidth).toString() + 'px'; this.style.width='100%'; this.style.height='auto';" src="yourimage.jpg" />
```

If you don't want to change the image tag use a javascript funtction on all images.

```
function makeImagesResponsive(){
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
        images[i].style.maxWidth=(images[i].getAttribute('width')?images[i].getAttribute('width'):images[i].naturalWidth).toString() + 'px';
        images[i].style.width='100%';
        images[i].style.height='auto';  
    }
}
window.addEventListener( "load", makeImagesResponsive, false );
```

Of course you can select only images from specific sections of your web site, or filter them by class name or other attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, support for max-width on a table recently landed in Chrome.

I'm not sure if the fix was applied to Webkit, or just Chrome's Blink engine. The problem still affects Safari 6.