# Responsive images in tables (bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the Bootstrap 3 Framework and have some troubles with
the "img-responsive" class in Firefox.
I have a 4 column-Table with 15/50/10/25% layout.
In the first column is an large-image, which should be scaled down to the 15%.
But this only works in Chrome/Opera, but not in FF/IE (the images are not responsive and therefore too big).

My code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed voc_list ">

<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width:15%;"></th>
<th style="width:50%;">Bezeichnung</th>
<th style="width:10%;">Zeitraum</th>
<th style="width:25%;">Ort</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<tr class="listview">
<td style="padding:15px 0px 15px 0px;"> 
<a href="xy" title="">
<img src="yx.jpg" class="img-responsive voc_list_preview_img" alt="" title=""></a>
</td>

<td style="width: 50%; padding:15px 15px 15px 15px;">
<a href="xy" title="">
<h3 class="nomargin_top">ABC</h3>
</a>
</td>

<td style="width:10%;">
555
</td>

<td>
XYZ
</td>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Is this a known problem in BS3? I couldn't find anything.

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/cctyb/ - in Chrome it works, in FF the image is to big

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do Firefox and Opera ignore max-width inside of display: table-cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923710/why-do-firefox-and-opera-ignore-max-width-inside-of-display-table-cell)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

add `.img-responsive{width:100%;}` to your css, see also: [Why do Firefox and Opera ignore max-width inside of display: table-cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923710/why-do-firefox-and-opera-ignore-max-width-inside-of-display-table-cell)

Comment: thx this works..., so this seems to be more a browser problem than a bootstrap problem?

Comment: I don't know. I think there is nothing wrong with adding an image (with class img-responsive) to a table, so i will be an issue of Bootstrap. In addition i have post the issue here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10690

Comment: you could put this code inside
@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .img-responsive { width: 100% }
} so it doesn't make smaller images bigger when the viewport is xs

Comment: Thank you so much, was trying to make images responsive inside table.

Comment: Thanks! now img are responsive acordin table width ;)

Comment: This makes my single small images scale to the container.  For example my 300px images end up being stretched to 1000px.  How do we prevent the image stretching any larger than its actual pixel width?

Answer (score 16):

I also had this problem, the solution for me was "table-layout fixed"

```
.table-container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.table-cell-container {
    text-align: left;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    &.center{
        text-align: center;
    }
    img{
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 100%;

    }
}

<div class="table-container">
<div class="table-cell-container center">
         <img src="myimage.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="myimage" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding "table-layout: fixed" was the best answer for my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Bass

```
.img-responsive {
   width:100%;
}
```

does work, but it also scales up other images.

What I have done instead is create another class as

```
.img-responsive-2 { 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

and put it together with the original `.img-responsive` so that I have the flexibility to use it only for images in tables.

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" class="img-responsive img-responsive-2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('img.img-responsive').each(function(){
        // Remember image size
        var imgWidth = $(this).width();
        // hide image 
        $(this).hide();
        // if container width < image width, we add width:100% for image 
        if ( $(this).parent().width() < imgWidth ) { $(this).css('width', '100%'); }
        // show image
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

My custom css:

```
table .img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How is that different from the answer by Bass Jobsen?