# Why do my media queries for a table work in chrome but not firefox?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, media-queries

I am styling a custom menu bar with media queries so that it is responsive, and it works in chrome and safari but not firefox. I have tried using the class, the id, a hierarchy of classes, but firefox does not want to show it properly no matter what I do.

You can see the issue here: http://wanagogo.com
(inspect element to see the html)

These are the queries that are currently working in chrome:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.kidsnav {
width: 900px;
}}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
.kidsnav {
width: 700px;
}}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
.kidsnav {
width: 520px;
}}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.kidsnav {
width: 97%;
}}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.kidsnav {
width: 90%;
}}
```

Am I missing something? Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Works for me in Firefox 34.

Comment: so when you go to that link, the orange/yellow menu at the top sizes correctly as you shrink your browser width?

Comment: I stand corrected. The top menu does not resize in Firefox. However, it works if I add add `.kidsnav img { width:100%; }` to your existing CSS.

Comment: Possibly related to [Bug 975632](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=975632).

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of [Responsive images in tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846744/responsive-images-in-tables-bootstrap-3/1885903) and/or [Why do Firefox and Opera ignore max-width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923710/why-do-firefox-and-opera-ignore-max-width-inside-of-display-table-cell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using 2 Selectors to declare the Table:

1st:

`table#Table_01` on line 563

and then

`.kidsnav` on lines 560, 567, 571, 575 & 579 (repeated due to your media queries).

So It is all related to Specificity, Check it [**HERE**](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) and **[HERE](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)** for more info

**Edit**

to make your menu responsive you have  to do at least 2 things in your CSS:

**1st:** add `.kidsnav img {width:100%}`

**2nd:** change *`speel`* `width`, instead of `.speel {width:172px}` change to `.speel {width:100%}` `

Comment: sorry, I had just added that as an attempt to correct it as I was writing this question. adding it doesnt work, removing it doesnt work. it is now removed. 
although, you may be right that it has to do with specificity. will investigate.