# Bootstrap responsive image in table fails in IE11

Tags: image, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, internet-explorer-11

I have a table cell that includes an image that should be 50% of the cell's width.

The code works in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, but in IE11 instead of taking on 50% of the cell's width, large images just take on 50% of their native size.

Here is a fiddle using a 800px wide image.  Works fine except in IE11, where the image displays as 400px wide instead of responsive: 
https://jsfiddle.net/43Tesseracts/9knqerj7/4/

Here is the relevant html with bootstrap:

```
    <td>
          <img src="http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Images-2.jpg"
             style="max-width:50%;"
             >
          The image beside me should appear 50% of the cell, not 50% of it's native size.  WOorks in Chrome, FF, Edge, but NOT IE 11
    </td>
```

There appear to be many similar issues on SE, but they are all much older, or use an older version of Bootstrap.  I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: Have you tried Bass Jobsen [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18859037/5588347)? Also try to set `max-width:100%`

Comment: Yes and yes. I was able to reproduce in a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/43Tesseracts/jtL6qujL/1/

Comment: Did i solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

there is no need for extra div's. you can set the following css property on the table element:

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

i updated your fiddle with a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/9knqerj7/10/

(in addition, i changed the img to be a block element and float left, but that is not required for the responsiveness - just looks better IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this issue using divs like i did here:

```
<td>
    <div style="display: flex;">
        <div style="width: 50%">
            <img src="http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Images-2.jpg" style="width: 100%">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%">
            THe image beside me should appear 50% of the cell, not 50% of it's native size.  WOorks in Chrome, FF, Edge, but NOT IE 11
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/9knqerj7/8/