# How to make responsive image in table with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to make image responsive in `<td>` section in table using bootstrap?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the code you have tried, and are stuck with? It's very difficult to help without seeing what has been attempted so far.

Comment: Its possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846744/responsive-images-in-tables-bootstrap-3 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive images in tables (bootstrap 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846744/responsive-images-in-tables-bootstrap-3)