# Table not responsive in Firefox, Works in Chrome

Tags: html, css

First of all let see this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6eELM/1/)** by resizing in firefox and chrome,

I also tried this [Why do Firefox and Opera ignore max-width inside of display: table-cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923710/why-do-firefox-and-opera-ignore-max-width-inside-of-display-table-cell) but no sucess.

```
table img { display:block }
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Ok let me make a fiddle

Comment: @Quentin Fiddle Added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this <kbd>[**demo jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6eELM/2/)</kbd>

You use `max-width`, but actually It's meaning `original image size`. that's why not working on firefox. you should modify `max-width` to `width` and assign `100%` to work on all browser.

#### CSS

```
 img {
    width: 100%;  // before: max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: update with media query http://jsfiddle.net/6eELM/3/ below 600 pixel will only update above code

Comment: @PravinVaichal thank you for showing jsfiddle with extra added media query code.

Comment: No probs guys you might be interested to check this out http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps really helpful