# an Li element is out of the div in firefox but iside the div in chrome?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox, browser

in the below page you will find an element

[website](http://qualityfoodeg.com/about.html)

```
 <li role="presentation">
  <a href="#ragab" aria-controls="ragab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
   <img class="img-thumbnail" src="photos/clients/ragab.jpg" />
```

is out of the Row in firefox but inside the row in chrome ??

any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<li>` elements are `display: table-cell` (from Bootstrap).
Your `<img>` elements are `max-width: 100%` (from your style.css).
The w3.org spec states that max-width does not apply to inline elements, so you will get inconsistent behavior across browsers.
See this answer: [Why do Firefox and Opera ignore max-width inside of display: table-cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923710/why-do-firefox-and-opera-ignore-max-width-inside-of-display-table-cell)
You can put `width: 100%` instead.

Comment: THANK YOU so much
it worked and i'm trying to read more to fully understand it