# <table> Force images to fit

Tags: html, css

How can I force images inside of a `<table>` to fit? Images that are larger than the container stretch it out.
This CSS works in Chrome and other browsers but does not work in Firefox, what should I use?

```css
.scaleimages img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do Firefox and Opera ignore max-width inside of display: table-cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923710/why-do-firefox-and-opera-ignore-max-width-inside-of-display-table-cell)

Comment: No nothing from that thread worked however since I am using a fixed width board I realized I didn't have to set max-width to 100%, I could assign it the width of the container.

Comment: Can you add a snippet or fiddle with this problem?